# Indexing Armadillo cx_cube non-continuous rows

Tags: cube, armadillo

I am currently converting MATLAB to C++ with armadillo. I have a somewhat large cx_cube, 900x251x64, and I have uvec, "index", that I would like to use to index into the cube like so:

```
data(index,:,:);//matlab version
```

Looking at armadillo syntax I've thought about these 2.

```
Q.subcube(first_row,first_col,first_slice,last_row,last_col, last_slice); //"index" may or may not be continuous so won't work
Q.rows(index); // not proper syntax
```

It looks like my only 2 options would be

```
Q.elem( vector_of_indices )
Q( vector_of_indices )
```

but I am not too sure on how they would work to grab the numbers that I need.

Answer (score 0):

Usually when converting MATLAB code to C++ with armadillo you want to reorder dimensions according to how you want to access it.
The api for [non-contiguous views for cubes](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#subcube) only includes individual element access with `Q.elem( vector_of_indices )` and `Q( vector_of_indices )`, or individual **slices access** with     `Q.slices( vector_of_slice_indices )`.

From your MATLAB code you seem to want to access individual matrices contained in the 3D array using you vector of indexes. In that case the non-contiguous view specifying slice indexes will work. All you need to do is using the third dimension instead of the first one when converting your MATLAB code to armadillo. That is, if the cube has dimension 251x64x900 you can easily access matrices with 251x64 dimension as slices.